# Generic way to instantiate an object name and set its values

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I was wondering if there was a way that allows you to create an object using a string 
like

```
Class<?> classObject = Class.forName("Client");
Object object = classObject.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

but be able to set the values of the variables to the name of the field

so:

```
Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (int i=0; i< fields.length; i++)
{
    object.???????? = fields[i].getName();
}
```

so I would have object.name = "name", object.address = "address" etc

I'm not sure how to use the properties of the instance I have created.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little example of how to do it:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> object = Class.forName("test.Property");
    Object o = object.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    System.out.println(o);
    Field testField = object.getDeclaredField("test");
    Field nameField = object.getDeclaredField("name");
    testField.setAccessible(true);
    testField.set(o, "Hello");
    testField.setAccessible(false);
    nameField.setAccessible(true);
    nameField.set(o, "Name");
    nameField.setAccessible(false);
    System.out.println(o);
  }

}

class Property {

  private String test;
  private String name;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Property{" + "test=" + (test == null ? "null" : test) + ", name=" + (name == null ? "null" : name) + '}';
  }
}
```